# Is there any problem in Installing Sharepoint foundation patches and CU inside sharepoint server 2013 professional

Tags: sharepoint-server, installation, configuration, configuration-wizard, patching

I have live & staging SharePoint servers 2013. and i have installed the November 2014 CU on both of them, then i run the product configuration wizard. now when i run the following command on both servers

```
(get-spfarm).buildversion
```

on live i got:-

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
15     0      4641   1000
```

while on staging i got:-

```
PS C:\> (Get-SPFarm).BuildVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
15     0      4667   1000
```

so why i have different build numbers (4641 & 4667). i have noted on my live server that windows update tool is showing the following update for  SharePoint foundation server http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2899508  (this update was installed by mistake inside my staging), so could this update cause the difference ?

second question. is there any problem of installing SharePoint foundation updates inside SharePoint server 2013 professional ?

**EDIT**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`​15.0.4641.1001` is for ​August 2014 CU while ​`15.0.4667.1000` is for ​November 2014 CU. [Check from Here](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=346)

So what i think, you installed the Aug 2014 CU on the Live servers while on staging Server You install the Correct the CU.

to fix this, simply download the [Nov 2014 CU](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2014/10/14/october-2014-cu-for-sharepoint-2013-has-been-released.aspx) for SharePoint Server and Install on all servers in farm than Run the Config wizard. Keep in mind, This required an outage so plan accordingly.

Their is no problem if you install the SharePoint foundation, But if you have Server then Install the SharePoint Server Binaries as SharePoint Server CU include the SharePoint Foundation as well.

Comment: now to clear my question better. windows update tool last week showed 4 CUs for SharePoint server 2013 (i have edit my original question with a picture). three of the CU are for sharepoint server , while on of them is for SP foundation. what i did is that on the live server i only installed the three cU regarding SP server, while i did not install the foundation CU. And that why my live server farm build number is still 4641. while on our staging server i have installed all the 4 CUs including the CU for foundation, and that why i got 4667 farm build number.

Comment: so this means that i should install the foundation CU on live server to get the 4667 farm build number, actually there are not other option. but my question is why windows update showed a foundation CU for my SharePoint server license, and why it did not shown the equivalent CU for SP server instead of the foundation CU ?